# Will "==" evaluate as "===" in JS strict mode?

Tags: javascript, strict

In JS, I understand the difference between the non-strict equality operator `==` and the strict equality operator `===` and how they evaluate different expressions differently, for example `0 == false` but `0 !== false`. However, their names, "strict" and "non-strict" have led me to question their evaluations in strict mode. For example, if I had the following code:

```js
// some code ...

function name(parameters) {
  'use strict';

  // my question is, within this strict evaluated function, will '==' evaluate as '==='?

  if (parameters == '') {
    throw new Error(`Expected a valid value for parameters, but got ${parameters}`);
  }
}
```

Because this is in strict mode, if I pass `0` into `parameters`, will it throw the error because `0 == ''`, or will it evaluate it as `0 === ''`, which would return `false`? This is just an example to illustrate my question (in the title).

My guess is that the answer is no, but it is possible that strict mode will evaluate everything strictly, including these equality operators.

Also, is there any documentation that will show this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode lists all the changes that are made by `use strict`.

Comment: Strict mode is completely separate from "strict" comparison, which ensures type and value equality (so no coercion).

Comment: Yes documentation describes the answer, starting from the language specification.

Comment: It's unfortunate that they chose the same term to describe them, but that's life.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I was pretty sure it would not evaluate as such, but I wasn't sure, so this verifies my answer.

Comment: `===` is called "Strict equality comparison" (no relation to strict mode), `==` is called "Abstract equality comparison"

Comment: If you have an answer, **put it in the answer section**.